# Using dplyr to mark areas

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to create an area column in a dataset where I specify a coordinate range and it should input the corresponding area based on the condition. The code I used is as follows:

I have used dplyr and with multiple ifelse to do it but it doesnt seem to give me the right result.

```
train = train %>%
  mutate(area = ifelse(cood < 3750023.25, 'Area 1',
                   ifelse(3750023.25 >= cood & cood < 3759048.50, 'Area 2',
                          ifelse(3759048.50 >= cood & cood < 3768073.75, 'Area 3',
                                 ifelse(3768073.75 >= cood, 'Area 4', NA)))))
```

The results are not really matching what I should expect. for example the first row has a cood of 3751013 but it is giving me Area 3 when it should give me Area 2. What can be going wrong in this?

Comment: use `case_when` function.

Comment: Better use `cut` instead

Comment: 3751013 is not being assigned to 'Area 2' because it doesn't satisfy the requirements in your `ifelse()`:

`3750023.23 >= 3751013 = FALSE`

Comment: @djfinnoy that was exactly the problem, thank you! It was just a confusion in the calculation

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments, use [`case_when`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html).

```
train = train %>%
  mutate(area = case_when(cood < 3750023.25 ~ 'Area 1', 
                          3750023.25 >= cood & cood < 3759048.50 ~ 'Area 2',
                          3759048.50 >= cood & cood < 3768073.75 ~ 'Area 3',
                          3768073.75 >= cood ~ 'Area 4',
                          TRUE ~ NA))
```